# May I add a GetMutableSizePrefixedRoot (or GetSizePrefixedMutableRoot)?

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

We are using flatbuffers with size prefixed buffers and want to mutate a flatbuffer but there is no GetMutableSizePrefixedRoot or GetSizePrefixedMutableRoot.

I could make a PR and add one like that.

```
template<typename T> T *GetMutableSizePrefixedRoot(void *buf) {
  return GetMutableRoot<T>(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(buf) +
                           sizeof(uoffset_t));
}
```

I could also change the code generator so that a GetMutableSizePrefixedXXX (e.g. GetMutableSizePrefixedMonster) will be generated .

Comment: Yes, you could probably just make a PR for that